# Carry forward last non-NA date across multiple columns into one column

Tags: r, na

I'd like to create a column that contains the "last" non-NA date value from a series of columns:

```
type<-c("a","b","c","d")
date1<-c("2019-01-01","2019-01-01",NA,NA)
date2<-c("2018-03-01",NA,NA,NA)
date3<-c(NA,NA,"2019-06-11",NA)
score<-c("y","n","y","y")
finaldate<-NA
data.frame(type,date1,date2,date3,score,finaldate)


   type      date1      date2      date3 score finaldate
1    a 2019-01-01 2018-03-01       <NA>     y        NA
2    b 2019-01-01       <NA>       <NA>     n        NA
3    c       <NA>       <NA> 2019-06-11     y        NA
4    d       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     y        NA
```

Desired output is for finaldate to have:

2018-03-01, 2019-01-01, 2019-06-11, and NA/null as its values.

I've seen examples using `na.locf()` but doesn't seem to be working for me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean "last" as in the maximum date; or of columns date1,date2,date3 the "last one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`na.locf0` can be used like this.  It also works with `na.locf` or `na.omit` in place of `na.locf0`.

```
library(zoo)

Last <- function(x) tail(na.locf0(x), 1)
transform(DF, finaldate = apply(DF[2:4], 1, Last))
```

giving:

```
  type      date1      date2      date3 score  finaldate
1    a 2019-01-01 2018-03-01       <NA>     y 2018-03-01
2    b 2019-01-01       <NA>       <NA>     n 2019-01-01
3    c       <NA>       <NA> 2019-06-11     y 2019-06-11
4    d       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     y       <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `coalesce`.   According to `?coalecse`

> Given a set of vectors, coalesce() finds the first non-missing value at each position.

So, we welect the 'date' columns in reverse and use `coalesce` to select the first non-NA element.  Note, here we use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to have the columns as `character` instead of `factor` (it would also work if the columns are class `Date`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(finaldate = coalesce(!!! .[4:2]))
# type      date1      date2      date3 score  finaldate
#1    a 2019-01-01 2018-03-01       <NA>     y 2018-03-01
#2    b 2019-01-01       <NA>       <NA>     n 2019-01-01
#3    c       <NA>       <NA> 2019-06-11     y 2019-06-11
#4    d       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     y       <NA>
```

---

Also, can use `tidyhelpers` to select the columns of interest

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(finaldate = coalesce(!!!  select(., rev(starts_with("date")))))
```

---

Or in `base R` we can use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(df[4:2], na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(type,date1,date2,date3,score,finaldate, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can also use `max.col` with `ties.method = "last"` to select last non-NA value in selected columns.

```
cols <- grep("^date", names(df))
df$final_date <- df[cols][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
                 max.col(!is.na(df[cols]), ties.method = "last"))]

df
#  type      date1      date2      date3 score final_date
#1    a 2019-01-01 2018-03-01       <NA>     y 2018-03-01
#2    b 2019-01-01       <NA>       <NA>     n 2019-01-01
#3    c       <NA>       <NA> 2019-06-11     y 2019-06-11
#4    d       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     y       <NA>
```